# How can I check two conditions before inserting?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have three tables:

```
// Posts
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
| id |  title   |    content    | id_author |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
| 1  | title1   | content1      | 1234      |
| 2  | title2   | content2      | 5678      |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+

// Users
+----+--------+--------+
| id |  name  | active |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | jack   | 1      |
| 2  | peter  | 0      |
| 3  | John   | 1      |
+----+--------+--------+

// Votes
+----+---------+---------+
| id | id_post | id_user |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 32      | 1234    |
| 2  | 634     | 5678    |
| 3  | 352     | 1234    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Now I need to check two conditions before inserting a new vote into `Votes` table:

1. The id of author and what I have passed are the same? `Posts.id_user = :author` *(I know I can do that by a FK, but I don't want)*
2. The account of current user is active? `Users.active = 1`

Also here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO Votes (id_post,id_user)
SELECT ?,?
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.id_user = :author limit 1;
```

How can I add second condition `Users.active = 1` to my query?

---

**EDIT:** Actually I'm trying to don't let people be able to vote who are inactive *(`active = 0`)*. For example if SO bans men, then I cannot vote to post anymore, because I (current user) am banned. So I'm pretty sure `$_SESSION['id']` should be used in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Votes (id_post,id_user)
SELECT p.id,u.id
FROM Posts p, Users u
WHERE p.id_user = :author
AND u.id = :user
AND u.active = 1 limit 1;
```

then you set parameter `user` equal to the current user id.

**EDIT**: I suppose `id_user` in table `Votes` must be the voter's id, not the author of the post (correct?), so I fixed the query eliminating the `JOIN`.

Comment: Look, I'm trying to check whether **current user** is active or not. So I think I have to use `$_SESSION['id']` in the query.

Comment: I have edited the query. `author` is the post author and `user` is the current voter.

Answer (score 0):

Use and with where

```
INSERT INTO Votes (id_post,id_user)
SELECT ?,?
FROM Posts p, Users u 
WHERE p.id_user = :author and u.active = 1 limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Votes (id_post,id_user)
SELECT p.id, u.id
FROM Posts p
    INNER JOIN Users u ON 1 = 1
WHERE p.id_user = :author
    AND u.id = :current_user_id
    AND u.active = 1
LIMIT 1;
```