# listing unique sellers and buyers

Tags: sql

I have these tables

```
Customer (Customer_ID(PK), Joined_date, FirstName, LastName, Location) 
Seller (Seller_ID, Customer_ID(Fk)) and Buyer(Buyer_ID, Customer_ID(FK))
```

I need to show only those buyers and sellers who have joined after 1st jan 2016 and that person should not be listed twice who sold an item and also bought an item.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT BUYER_FirstName, BUYER_LastName, SELLER_ID 
    FROM BUYER AS BUY 
    UNION 
    SELECT SELLER_FirstNAME,Seller_LastName, BUYER_ID 
    FROM SELLER AS SELL
) WHERE JOINED_DATE > TO_DATE('01-01-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') 
ORDER BY JOINED_DATE;
```

am i on the right track? actually i had to run these queries conceptually based on ER Diagram.

Comment: Create the tables and do some testing! (You'll notice JOINED_DATE will cause you some problems as it's used in the WHERE clause.)

Comment: will it return the desired results?

Comment: The data model isn't perfectly designed. Now the same person can have different JOINED_DATE, one as seller and one as buyer.

Comment: As you might already know, you cannot use random typographic quotes like `’` as string delimiter. The fact that they show up in the question suggests you're possibly not using an appropriate text editor.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: please can someone rectify the query and let me know :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably contort your approach to get the answer.  However, I would be more inclined to start with the customer table (assuming that both buyers and sellers are customers).

```
select c.*
from customers c
where c.join_date >= '2016-01-01' and
      exists (select 1 from buyers b where b.customer_id = c.customer_id) and
      exists (select 1 from sellers s where s.customer_id = c.customer_id);
```

Note:  In Oracle you need to put `date` before the date constant.

This rephrases the question to getting customers who joined since the first of the year who have made both a purchase and a sale.

Comment: ++ May you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978099/how-can-i-check-two-conditions-before-inserting)